# Tried to plot a graph in R but getting an message

Tags: r, plot, graph

I want to plot a grpah in R but it returned an error. I don't know why this happen. Please help me.

```
theta <- exp(seq(-100,100,by=0.01)) 
theta <- c(-theta,theta) 
theta <- theta[order(1/theta)]
    
    
pdf("plot.pdf") 
plot(-1/(2*theta^2),1/theta,type="l",xlab="w1",ylab="w2",xaxt="n",yaxt="n") 
abline(h=0) 
abline(v=0) 
dev.off()
```

When I run all the codes together and it keeps return this error.

```
> dev.off()
pdf 
  2
```

Sometimes I just get this message instead.

```
> dev.off()
null device 
          1
```

It turns out that I can have my graph as a PDF format file. But I wonder why this type of message keep showing each time when I run my codes. What do they mean?

Comment: I don't see any error. Which error are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry. I just edited my post. I want to know why it will show these 2 message to me each time when I run my codes.

Comment: They are not error message, it just indicates the number and name of the active device